# Update MainWindow when Window2 Closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a two window application. I am opening windows2 from my mainwindow. I want to update the mainWindow (change text for example) when the window2 closed. How am I able to do that.

Here is my mainWindow

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window2 secondForm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            secondForm = new Window2();
            secondForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this via passing a reference the MainWindow.

Comment: @kanchirk can you share an example please?

Comment: @uesr1936285 let me know if you did not follow something in the example pasted below.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        SecondForm form = new SecondForm();
        form.Closed += form_Closed;
        form.Show();
    }

    void form_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        llMsg.Content = "The second form is closed";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via passing a reference the MainWindow.

Add a property called MainWindow of type Window in Window2 class

```
public Window MainWindow { get;set;}
```

Then updated the button1_click method as below.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                secondForm = new Window2();
                secondForm.MainWindow = this;
                 secondForm.OnClosing += (sfO,sfE)=>{ if(MainWindow!=null){
MainWindow.SomeProperty = "Second Window was closed.";
} };
                secondForm.Show();
            }
```

I am using a Lambda expression syntax to trap the OnClosing event.

Comment: Please don't teach extremely bad habits. The only form that should be updating `MainWindow` is MainWindow itself. `secondForm` should return a value which MainWindow receives and acts upon.

Comment: @slugster You have a good point. Can you please provide an example to accomplish the same. Will appreciate it.